# WWII (?) comic about a spy doing propaganda for the bad guys

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, comics

**The story, so far...**

When I was a kid, I read a story about a guy, who was sent to a country as a spy. He ended up working with doing propaganda for said countrys government, but is secretly sending messages to resistance people, informing them on weapon drops and warning people about where raids will be conducted and who is suspected of being with the resistance etc.
In the end, it is revealed that the government knew he was a spy (or at least suspected it), but they didn't care, because he was doing such a good job recruting and keeping morals high, that whatever they lost, was easily gained back.

**What else**

- I read the story back in the mid 90'es, but it is possible that the comic was actually older than that
- I think it was a short story and not a full comic in it self.
- I also read a lot of Tales from the Crypt/Creepshow, and I have a feeling that it could be one of those "I thought I was doing good, but actually did bad" stories. This also fits with it story being a short, and not a full comic.
- It is quite possible that the setting was WWII and the guy was from one of the allied countries, the bad guys (of course) being the Nazis.
- I do believe that the comic itself was in black and white

I've been searching for the story using key terms, but "WWII propaganda comic" really covers a lot and I cannot think of any names or places, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Kurt Vonnegut's *Mother Night* although that wasn't a comic - maybe there was a comic adaptation of it?